# About Threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a small python program made by myself which scrape a website for some prices. I am using beautifulsoup 4 and python threading module.

The problem is I dont know how to "control" the threads. As you can see from the code, I made subclass of threading class (something like consumer, producer). In one class I am taking links from the pages, and in the other I am looking for some classes at the html with BS4 and writing to the major file.

When I start the script, I am normally starting with Thread 1. I am scraping for every link at the website, taking name and article price. For every link, I am making thread. As the website has many links (around 3000), after some time, I have that much threads which are killing my computer. Python.exe is around 2 GB and I have to kill the program.

This is my fourth day trying to find a solution...... Please.... :)

If I get it right: setDaemon(true) - the program kills them after execution, .join() is waiting to complete the thread.

I am totally beginner in the programming and also aware that the code is little messy. Any suggestions are welcome.

Dont worry about last few try blocks. Its just for the fun.

Thank you!

```
import threading
import csv
import urllib2
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import Queue


httpLink = "WWW.SOMEWEBSITE.COM"
fn = 'J:\\PRICES\\'

queue = Queue.Queue()
soup_queue = Queue.Queue()
brava = threading.Lock()

links = []
brokenLinks = []
pageLinks = []

fileName = time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y-%H_%M")


class TakeURL(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, soup_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.soup_queue = soup_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            host = self.queue.get()
            try:
                url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
                chunk = url.read()
            except:
                print ("Broken link " + host)
                writeCSV("BrokenLinks.csv", "ab", host)
                brokenLinks.append(host)
                time.sleep(30)

            writeCSV('Links.csv','ab',host)

            if ("class=\"price\"" in chunk):
                self.soup_queue.put(chunk)                
            else:
                writeCSV("LinksWithoutPrice.csv", "ab", host)
                try:
                    findLinks(chunk, "ul", "mainmenu")
                except:
                    print ("Broken Link" + host)
                    writeCSV("BrokenLinks.csv", "ab", host)
                    brokenLinks.append(host)
                    time.sleep(30)                

            self.queue.task_done()

class GetDataURL(threading.Thread):
    getDataUrlLock = threading.Lock()
    def __init__ (self, soup_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.soup_queue = soup_queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            chunk = self.soup_queue.get()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(chunk)
            dataArticle = soup.findAll("tr",{"class":""})
            pagination = soup.findAll("a",{"class":"page"})

            self.getDataUrlLock.acquire()
            f = open(fn + fileName + ".csv", "ab")
            filePrice = csv.writer(f)
            for groupData in dataArticle:
                for articleName in groupData.findAll("a",{"class":"noFloat"}):
                    fullName = articleName.string.encode('utf-8')
                    print (fullName)
                for articlePrice in groupData.findAll("div", {"class":"price"}):
                    if (len(articlePrice) > 1):
                        fullPrice = articlePrice.contents[2].strip()
                    else:
                        fullPrice = articlePrice.get_text().strip()
                    print (fullPrice[:-12])
                    print ('-')*80        

                filePrice.writerow([fullName, fullPrice[:-12]])
            f.close()

            for page in pagination:
                pageLink = page.get('href')
                pageLinks.append('http://www.' + pageLink[1:])
            self.getDataUrlLock.release()

            self.soup_queue.task_done()

def writeCSV(fileName, writeMode, link):
    try:
        brava.acquire()
        f = csv.writer(open(fn + fileName,writeMode))
        f.writerow([link])        
    except IOError as e:
        print (e.message)
    finally:
        brava.release()

def findLinks(chunk, tagName, className):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(chunk)
    mainmenu = soup.findAll(tagName,{"class":className})
    for mm in mainmenu:
        for link in mm.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            links.insert(0,href)            
            print (href)
            print ('-')*80

def startMain(links):
    while (links):
        #time.sleep(10)
        threadLinks = links[-10:]        

        print ("Alive Threads: " + str(threading.activeCount()))
        #time.sleep(1)

        for item in range(len(threadLinks)):
            links.pop()

        for i in range(len(threadLinks)):
            tu = TakeURL(queue, soup_queue)
            tu.setDaemon(True)
            tu.start()            

        for host in threadLinks:
            queue.put(host)

        for i in range(len(threadLinks)):
            gdu = GetDataURL(soup_queue)
            gdu.setDaemon(True)
            gdu.start()

        queue.join()
        soup_queue.join()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()

    httpWeb = urllib2.urlopen(httpLink)
    chunk = httpWeb.read()
    findLinks(chunk, 'li','tab')

        startMain(links)
        pageLinks = list(set(pageLinks))
        startMain(pageLinks)
        startMain(brokenLinks)

    print ('-') * 80
    print ("Seconds: ") % (time.time() - start)
    print ('-') * 80
```

Comment: http://sscce.org! please try to narrow your problem down to a **simple** code to read!

Comment: i tried man... but i dont know where to start or how to take this down... so if you dont want to read, no problem with me.... sorry... anyway, this can be some full live example here... so i would like to leave as is... :)

Comment: Read [Parallelism in One Line](https://medium.com/building-things-on-the-internet/40e9b2b36148). It goes over how to set up parallelism easily in a Python programming using the example of scraping websites.

Comment: @xbonez.... this is wonderfull.... thank you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thread never returns anything, so it never stops; just continually runs the `while` loop.  And since you're starting a new thread for each link, you eventually just keep adding on more and more threads while previous threads may not be doing anything.  You essentially wouldn't need a `queue` with the way you have it.  This approach can cause problems with a large number of jobs, as you're noticing.

`worker = GetDataURL()`
`worker.start()`

really points to `GetDataURL.run()`...which is an infinite while loop.
Same is true for `TakeURL.start()`.

You could go a couple routes

1) Just take the while out of your thread, do away with the queues and return the result at the **end** of the `run` definition.  This way each thread has 1 task, returns the results, then stops.  Not the most efficient but would require the least amount of code modification.

2) In your `startMain`, outside of the `while` loop, start a group of say 10 threads (i.e. a thread pool). These 10 threads will always run, and instead of starting a new thread for each link, just put the link in the queue.  When a thread is available, it will run the next item in queue.  But you still need to manage the cleanup of these threads.

3) You could rework your code a bit more and make use of built in functions like Thread Pools and Process Pools.  I've posted on Process Pools before: [SO MultiProcessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200884/using-threading-multiprocessing-in-python-to-do-multiple-calculations-at-the-sam/21201720#21201720)
With this method, you can forget all the mess associated with locks too.  After each pool.map (or whatever you use) you can right that chunk of information to the file in your `startMain` code.  Cleans things up a lot.

Hopefully that makes some sense.  I chose not to modify your code cause I think it's worth you experimenting with the options and choosing a direction.

Comment: Added a few more comments

Comment: @catwalker... i have removed while loops and now i can see the problem.... thank you for the guidance... your answer with xbonez site makes me this little more clear.